# Parse log and export to CSV

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I am in need of help completing this script with additional details after export. What I need to do is run this to multiple machines and export to CSV. I'd like to have Computer name in the first column and then the string containing the error on the second column. I'd like to export the CSV to `\\servername\folder\...`.

```
Get-Content "$env:windir\Panther\setuperr.log" | Where-Object {
    $_.Contains("Can't retrieve group.........")
} | Select-Object -Last 1
```

Comment: Great! So what have you done to try and accomplish your goals, and how is it failing you?

Comment: Please, have a look at the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Add e.g. a part of a log file to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this via PowerShell [remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enable-psremoting?view=powershell-6). Since you didn't post anything about the machines you want to query I'm assuming the following:

- You're using PowerShell 5.x
- Your remotes are WindowServer 2012 R2, or higher, or Win10
- PS remoting is allowed and activated based on these [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enable-psremoting?view=powershell-6)

If so, you can use `Invoke-Command` via combination via the `-ComputerName` or `-Session` parameter set. Here is the `Invoke-Command` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-6). Simple example:

```
$computerNames = "pc1.domain", "pc2.domain"

$results = @()
foreach ($computerName in $computerNames) {
    $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $computerName -Credential (Get-Credential)        
    $result = Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
       # Lets assume that this code from OP is correct
       $foundRow = Get-Content "$env:windir\Panther\setuperr.log" | Where-Object {
          $_.Contains("Can't retrieve group.........") } | Select-Object -Last 1
       # Return custom object to caller
       [PSCustomObject]@{
           FoundRow = $foundRow
           ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
       }
    }
    $results += $result
}
```

`$results` is an array of objects, where each object contains a `FoundRow` and `ComputerName` property. This objects piped to the `Export-Csv` ([docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-6)) cmdlet:

```
$results | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\temp\your.csv
```

If you don't want to type the credentials every time you could create a CSV file containing computer name and encrypted credentials. This [link](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/04/21/using-saved-credentials-securely-in-powershell-scripts/) explains how to store the credentials in an encrypted way. To walk through the data you can use `Get-Content` and `ConvertFrom-Csv` cmdlets.

Hope that helps.